# Find value in range sql

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent

Lets say i had a bunch of records and they had a column max_val and min_val. lets assume min_val is 1 and max_val is 55 how would i use sql or eloquent orm to find records that fit the description of a value of 14? i.e 14 falls between min_val and max_val? 
Thanks

Comment: your question has the answer too. `select .... where colWithValue14 between ...`

Comment: Are you talking about one column(val) or two columns (max_val and min_val)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use the BETWEEN operator. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE 14 BETWEEN min_value AND max_value;
```

which is roughly equal to

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE min_value <= 14 AND max_value >= 14;
```